# C++: variable declaration initialization order

Tags: c++

When I'm defining some variables like this:

```
int a = pop(), b = pop(), c = pop();
```

does C++ give a guarantee that `a` is going to be initialized first, then `b` and then `c`? or is the order not defined?

Comment: Could you explain why this is important? We might give a better answer

Comment: I want to write just one line instead of 3 lines :)

Comment: Improve readability and assert your order by using 3 lines. It's as simple as that. What's the point of getting rid of two lousy lines anyway?

Comment: I agree with @stefan. I rarely (never?) use multiple declarations in one line.

Comment: If this occurs in a _for-init-statement_ such as `for (int a = pop(), b = pop(), c = pop(); ...)` then the question is more interesting. You _could_ put two of the declarations on the previous line, but now they have a different scope

Answer (score 12):

[dcl.decl]/3 says

> -3- Each init-declarator in a declaration is analyzed separately as if it was in a declaration by itself.

Which means your code is treated like:

```
int a = pop();
int b = pop();
int c = pop();
```

Comment: Hmm - I'm not convinced that this implies a predictable order of initialisation...

Comment: which still doesn't guarantee any particular order.

Comment: Note 97 provides an explanation, but uses the work "usually". I believe, however, that this only means that there are well-defined exceptions to this rule, but it is not "up to the compiler".

Comment: @aleguna, are you saying that the second bit of code, with each declaration in a separate statement, doesn't guarantee any particular order?

Comment: @JonathanWakely: I think they're saying that `int c = pop(); int b = pop(); int a = pop();` would also "analyze each init-declarator separately as if it was in a declaration by itself". So the text you quote doesn't *necessarily* mean what you go on to say that it means. IIRC there are examples in this bit of the standard that certainly suggest the order is retained.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: so arguably a (minor) defect in the standard, if one has to rely on a footnote for a normative statement of the required behavior. But I think you're correct about what the standard *intends* to define :-) In such moments I usually say that although footnotes aren't normative, they generally are true.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: yes, I've just noticed that. [dcl.init] is exactly the place, and in fact in the note #97 (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf) it is quite clearly stated that the `T a,b,c` is a "sequence" and is equivalent to `T a;T b;T c;`. The word "usually" refers not to exception in the comprehension of a sequence, but to the potential collision of identifiers: `T a, T, b, c;` is surely not equivalent to `T a; T T; T b; T c;`. Therefore I agree that it is defined, but damn, I'd like   it to be written plainly as a proper point, not a footnote..