# Does int a=1, b=a++; invoke undefined behavior?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, sequence-points

Does `int a=1, b=a++;` invoke undefined behavior? There is no sequence point intervening between the initialization of `a` and its access and modification in the initializer for `b`, but as far as I can tell, initialization is not "modification" of the object; an initializer is specified to give the "initial value" of the object. Per 6.7.8 Initialization, paragraph 8:

> An initializer specifies the initial value stored in an object.

and it seems reasonable to take "initial" as being sequenced before any access to the object. Has this issue been considered before, and is there an accepted interpretation?

Comment: I'd say Footnote 97 says that this is identical to `int a = 1; int b = a++;`.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Footnote 97 in what version (or draft) of the standard? Footnote numbers are much less stable than section numbers.

Comment: IIRC, in the newest versions of the standard, the concept of "sequence points" is being obsoleted. As to the footnotes, there was recently a discussion about a footnote that defined the order of processing of the declare-and-initialize construct, and that footnote is actually seems quite old and stable :)

Comment: @quetzalcoatl AFAIK, the new C standard has been ratified, the concept of sequence points hasn't become obsolete and there is no mention of any plans regarding sequence points in section 6.11 "Future language directions". Where did you get this information from? Are you sure you're not talking about C++?

Comment: Oh my.. indeed, I meant C++. I didn't notice the C lang, or rather, I unintentionally added ++ to it.. Anyways, if you are interested also in it, then I've just finished digging through thread and found the discussions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15248697/717732. Funny, the footnote number is the same;) Oh dear. Today's not my day.. Probably KerrekSB also meant the #97 from C++!

Comment: In c++ this was a defect reported by me (and it didnt matter whether it appears in one or two declarations), and will be fixed for c++14.

Comment: See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1343

Comment: Is this important? `int a=2, b=2;` seems both shorter and safer.

Comment: Obviously the code as written should not be used, but the concept may still apply.

Comment: @BoPersson: You are asking, like, "why bother about a+=x when we can then a=a+x". It is not important for it to be "important". It is allowed by the syntax, so we should be able to deduce either how it will behave or either know that's not undefined.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl - No. If the code is so complicated that we have to discuss what the result is, **if any**, we just shouldn't use it. Especially not when there is a simpler version, like `int a=2, b=2;`, which is both shorter and obvious to everyone. [IOCCC](http://www.ioccc.org/) is sometimes slightly fun, but not important.

Comment: @BoPersson: Seriously, I think you've misread the intent. You asked "is this important". I'm answering: yes, it is important, because the language permits it. It is not relevant here whether we should use it or not. Obviously, we should not use dereference-operator on a null-pointer, but the language permits it. Therefore, it is very important to (un)define what happens when you do it. Once the possibility to do so is removed from the language, then it will became truly unimportant. Let me just point out that the author explicitely asks for the standard and even used 'language-lawyer' tag..

Comment: The only place this might possibly come up in the real world is with a beautiful/hideous (depending on your perspective) macro used for initializers of some non-trivial object. However, lack of applicability of the construct has no bearing on the question at hand.

Comment: @BoPersson How much such code should be avoided is illustrated well by the fact that even you misread it: its result is the same as that of `int a = 2, b = 1;`.

Comment: @Daniel - Oh  :-} I was concerned about code intending to set `a` equal to 2 starting  out with `int a = 1, ...` and didn't see the the other results of the code. So, even if it doesn't cause any undefined behavior, it is **obviously** confusing. Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It doesn't invoke undefined behaviour. In 6.7.6 (3), it is stated

> A full declarator is a declarator that is not part of another declarator. The end of a full
>   declarator is a sequence point.

that the end of a full declarator is a sequence point.

```
int a = 1, b = a++;
     //  ^ end of full declarator
```

Comment: '6.7.6 (3)' <- what is that?

Comment: Section 6.7.6, paragraph 3, of the standard (well, the N1570 draft, since I don't have the money to buy an expensive standard I don't _really_ need). That section deals with declarators.