# Why doesn't comma operator seem to work between a "if" statement and an "else" statement in my code?

Tags: c, if-statement, comma-operator, sequence-points

I know a statement like the following (commas in place of semi-colons) looks odd:

```
 if(a<b)printf("Hello\n"),a+=5,b/=5,printf("%d,%d",a,b);
```

But it works perfectly fine and I had read that it's because `comma` here acts as a sequence point.I can understand this.But I just fail to understand why the following fails then,where I have used a `else` as well:

```
  if(a<b)printf("Hi\n"),else printf("Bye\n"),a+=5,b/=5,printf("%d,%d",a,b);
```

It gives the error `expected expression before 'else'`.

Why does the second statement gives error?In the first statement, we saw that `comma` acts as a sequence point.Then why it doesn't act so before `else`?What's special about the second case that causes error?Here's my full program:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a=30,b=45;

    //if(a<b)printf("Hello\n"),a+=5,b/=5,printf("%d,%d",a,b); //Works well
    if(a<b)printf("Hi\n"),else printf("Bye\n"),a+=5,b/=5,printf("%d,%d",a,b); 
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16262983/are-there-sequence-point-issues-with-statements-like-int-a-4-ptr-a-or-x

Comment: Forget everything Python (or any other non C/C++ language) ever taught you about a comma, which is an **operator** in C and C++.

Comment: @WhozCraig Well,the program attends to/evaluates all stuff to the left of the commas and returns only the one after the last comma.But it's being unfair to the `else` above.

Comment: @WhozCraig As per the answers I got on that link,comma,operator or not, is a sequence point unless used to separate function arguments,right?

Comment: @Dayalrai If I change it to `a>b` I get the same error.And by your logic(and what I too used to feel),statements should end with `;` only,but it's not so as comma is a sequence point here.Else we would be needing a `;` after the first `printf()` too.

Comment: In this case it is more than just a sequence point issue. It is a language issue. The formation of the statements you're presenting break conformance to **C99 §6.8.4 Selection Statements**.

Comment: @WhozCraig Please post it in an answer, along with the quote from the standard.

Comment: @Rüppell'sVulture I guess, that you mistake sequence point with statement. These are two different things and else requires to be preceeded by a statement, not by a sequence point.

Comment: @Rüppell'sVulture Jens actually hit is more succinctly than I could/did, and imho, correctly. The syntax breaks conformance with if-then-else but only because without a finished statement preceding the else it is left just dangling out there by its lonesome. I already up-voted his answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The comma operator expects an expression and the `else` part of an `if` `else` construct ain't an expression. Thus a comma followed by the keyword `else` is a syntax error.

Comment: +1 a simple as this may seem, it is right imho. the statement-finale of the if-portion is never finished and the comma-chain is presented a statement starting with **else**, thereby invalid. Nice answer, sir.

Comment: This may be useful too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132/expression-versus-statement/19224#19224

Answer (score 4):

Imagine, that:

```
(a, b)
```

is translated to:

```
{
    a;
    return here b;
}
```

In this case, `return here` means "insert in place of this expression". And indeed, `,` acts as a sequence point.

Then,

```
if (a<b) printf("Hello\n"), a+=5, b/=5, printf("%d,%d",a,b);
```

would look like:

```
if (a<b)
{
    printf("Hello\n");
    a += 5;
    b /= 5;
    return here printf("%d, %d", a, b);
}
```

But

```
if(a<b)printf("Hi\n"),else printf("Bye\n"),a+=5,b/=5,printf("%d,%d",a,b);
```

Would look like:

```
if (a < b)
{
    printf("Hi\n");
    else printf("Bye\n");
    a += 5;
    b /= 5;
    return here printf("%d, %d", a, b);
}
```

And the else inside does not make any sense. That's why compiler complaints.

In other words, `,` in C++ is an operator. So by the operator precedence,

```
if(a<b)printf("Hi\n"),else printf("Bye\n"),a+=5,b/=5,printf("%d,%d",a,b);
```

is interpreted as

```
if(a<b) ( printf("Hi\n"),else printf("Bye\n"),a+=5,b/=5,printf("%d,%d",a,b) );
```

Which clearly violates the C++ syntax rules.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the correct syntax of IF-ELSE statement. Compiler expects semicolon to know that IF is ended. So you are basically trying to enter sub if-else statement into the first one, but without new if.

```
if(a>=18 &a <=64)printf("adult\n"); 
else if(a<=17)printf("minor\n"); 
else printf("senior\n");
```

So, either the curly brackets "{}" indicate the IF region, or if they are missing,  IF statement valid until the first semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

In 2nd case **else** is no having matching **if**, what is happening here is after printf("Hi\n"), when else arrives compiler looks for if i.e else should come only after terminated if statement. so it is giving error.